# Flutter Bloc Login State always show failure

Tags: flutter, bloc

> i am writing Login app with flutter_bloc ,i'm facing some problem!

1. After i logged in ,i show login failed even i have response  *key* from client,also in shared Preferences.It always fail except loading.
   here is Logs:

   ````
   I/flutter (23617): Key From Api Provider:f6c3e63f1a95b0709d2b70075d0d592e0c4a5f85
   I/flutter (23617): f6c3e63f1a95b0709d2b70075d0d592e0c4a5f85 --> i have already saved key in 
   SharedPrefrences
   I/flutter (23617): Transition { currentState: LoginState {
   I/flutter (23617):       isUsernameValid: true,
   I/flutter (23617):       isPasswordValid: true,      
   I/flutter (23617):       isSubmitting: true,
   I/flutter (23617):       isSuccess: false,
   I/flutter (23617):       isFailure: false,
   I/flutter (23617):     }, event: LoginWithCredentialsPressed { username: yelinaung, 
   password: asdfghjkl12345 }, nextState: LoginState {
   I/flutter (23617):       isUsernameValid: true,
   I/flutter (23617):       isPasswordValid: true,      
   I/flutter (23617):       isSubmitting: false,
   I/flutter (23617):       isSuccess: false,<-----
   I/flutter (23617):       isFailure: true,
   I/flutter (23617):     } }```  


   2.I want to Navigate to home when login return key..,I think the problem is here in login_bloc

        `   @override
         Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(
           LoginEvent event,
         ) async* {
           if (event is LoginWithUserNamePass) {
             yield* _mapLoginWithUserNamePass(
                 username: event.username, password: event.password);
           }
         }

         Stream<LoginState> _mapLoginWithUserNamePass(
             {String username, String password}) async* {
           yield LoginState.loading();---->
           try {
            #####  final String  key = await _apiLoader.doLogin(username, password);##### problem 
           here?
            #####  _authenticationBloc.dispatch(LoggedInNow(key));####### problem here?
               yield LoginState.success();

           } catch (_) {
             yield LoginState.failure();
           }
         }
          }`
   ````

> If i remove above `yield LoginState.success()` it return **state-success** true .
>      **3**. if i exit app and reenter it agian it show Authenticated...as below

````
  I/flutter (23617): Authenticated { key: f6c3e63f1a95b0709d2b70075d0d592e0c4a5f85 }
  I/flutter (23617): LoggedIn```
and navigate to home screen ...
>Can someone solve this problem,thank .
````

Answer (score 0):

> Solved .. i change

````
          final String  key = await _apiLoader.doLogin(username, password);

          _authenticationBloc.dispatch(LoggedInNow(key));####### problem 
    here?
            yield LoginState.success();

        }```
TO====>

   ```try {
          await _apiLoader.doLogin(username, password);


            yield LoginState.success();

        }
````

and another problem is `_apiLoader.dologin is not Future<void> or it return value`
im idiot ;)